# What is the difference between a plane spanned by 2 vectors and the Cartesian product.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

I was studying linear algebra and I noticed that the set of all linear combinations of 2 non parallel vectors is $R^2$, and I Abe noticed that’s the same name given to the Cartesian product RxR. Is this just a coincidence or does it mean there’s some connection between these.

Comment: Assuming you're working in a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, the span of two linearly independent vectors is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is just the cartesian product $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ endowed with vector space structure of componentwise addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" Cartesian product we are used to visualize and think is given by the span of the two vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, i.e., the x-axis and the y-axis. But you can generate a $2$D plane with any two other vectors (as long as they are not parallel). What will change will be that a point in the plane will have two different components (what we call the x, y components), depending on the vectors spanning such plane.
What I just wrote is somehow informal but should give the idea.